# When fetching Sites from Microsoft Graph SDK, why are Lists null?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How do you obtain the Lists for a Site using the Microsoft Graph SDK in Java?

I obtain a graph client:

```
ClientCertificateCredentialsConfig credentials = (ClientCertificateCredentialsConfig) msGraphFetcherConfig.getCredentials();
graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(credentials.getClientId())
                    .tenantId(credentials.getTenantId())
                    .pfxCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials.getCertificateBytes()))
                    .clientCertificatePassword(credentials.getCertificatePassword())
                    .build(), scopes);
SitesRequestBuilder sites = graphClient.sites();
GetAllSitesRequestBuilder allSites = sites.getAllSites();
Consumer<GetAllSitesRequestBuilder.GetRequestConfiguration> getRequestConfigurationConsumer = getRequestConfiguration -> {
            getRequestConfiguration.queryParameters.select = new String[]{"lists"};
        };
GetAllSitesGetResponse getAllSitesGetResponse = allSites.get(getRequestConfigurationConsumer);
for (Site site : getAllSitesGetResponse.getValue()) {
    LOGGER.info("Site lists: {}", site.getLists());
```

For all `site` objects returned, the `Lists` are null.

I tried to use the select property to select Lists but that did not work either.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the request configuration. This fixes the issue:

```
        SitesRequestBuilder sites = graphClient.sites();
        GetAllSitesRequestBuilder allSites = sites.getAllSites();
        GetAllSitesGetResponse getAllSitesGetResponse = allSites.get();
        for (Site site : getAllSitesGetResponse.getValue()) {
            LOGGER.info("Site id: {}", site.getId());
            site = graphClient.sites().bySiteId(site.getId()).get((getRequestConfiguration -> {
                getRequestConfiguration.queryParameters.expand = new String[]{"lists"};
            }));
            LOGGER.info("Site lists: {}", site.getLists());
```